# Browser keep loading for https://xen-media.com/downloads

Tags: firefox, adminlte

i am developing  website using Adminlte and this package keep loading and i have check in the code there is no any package imports by that name is this is some thing to do with browser https://xen-media.com/downloads and i have tried to open this page no it's sending me 522

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by "youtube download helper" browser extension. Better remove it...